# ImageProcessor ERROR with existing content uploaded to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage, umbraco7, imageprocessor

I came here to see if this issue can be fixed. I had all my images stored in my /media/ folder but I put it on an Azure Blob Storage and it works fine.

Actually when I try to delete one of my old custom media content with images I get this error and I can't delete any of the medias uploaded before change it to Azure Blob Storage:

```
ERROR ImageProcessor.Web.HttpModules.ImageProcessingModule - 
ImageProcessor.Common.Exceptions.ImageProcessingException: ProcessImageAsync 597 : No image exists at D:\home\site\wwwroot\media\1034\case-659x420.jpg
```

Can somebody tell me what 's happening?
Thank you

**EDIT1**
This is the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6glk.png) on my blob.
Umbraco Stores the image full path somewhere?

**EDIT 2**
This is the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1Dlp.png) on BO.

Comment: Are you using a custom Umbraco FilesSystemProvider to go with ImageProcessor?

Comment: Yes. I'm using FilesSystemProvider  `<Provider alias="media" type="Our.Umbraco.FileSystemProviders.Azure.AzureBlobFileSystem, Our.Umbraco.FileSystemProviders.Azure"> ` with  `<add key="useDefaultRoute" value="true"/>` I don't know if this caould be the issue.

Comment: Cool I wrote that. `useDefaultRoute` shouldn't be a problem... You're using the virtual path provider yeah? Umbraco should only be preserving the relative path so I'm not sure why it would be searching the file system.

Comment: @JamesSouth where can I find the virtual path provider? All db urls have relative path so I really don't know...

Comment: It should be automatic but check your configs here.

https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/UmbracoFileSystemProviders.Azure#virtual-path-provider

Comment: @JamesSouth nothing or worst, I added some missing configs to the website and I lost all the images!

Comment: "lost all the images!"? What do you mean by that? This stuff all just works. Umbraco Cloud use it on all their websites.

Answer (score 0):

> Actually when I try to delete one of my old custom media content with images I get this error and I can't delete any of the medias uploaded before change it to Azure Blob Storage:

According to your description and error message, I guess the causing of the exception is you don't change the app settings in the web config.

I suggest you could try to add below codes in the web config's appsetting and try again.

```
<add key="AzureBlobFileSystem.DisableVirtualPathProvider" value="true" />
```

I think this will work well.
[image]

Comment: Please I edit the question adding an image of it, they are all with this policy. But I don't know how is this asking for a system source when all have relative source.

Comment: I made this changes and it gave me the same result, backoffice error
`ERROR ImageProcessor.Web.HttpModules.ImageProcessingModule - 
ImageProcessor.Common.Exceptions.ImageProcessingException: ProcessImageAsync 597 : No image exists at D:\home\site\wwwroot\media\1034\case-659x420.jpg`

Comment: Update the answer.

Comment: I tried too.  See the second image on the Edited 2. there is the error on the BO and the  properties. What I have is a custom media type with an image on it.

Comment: Could you find the image file in the blob storage or you could find this file in the local?

Comment: It cant be found on the blob and the images are still there. If I remove some of the old ones, they still on the blob but the site do not delete it, throwing the error and I cant do anything with it.

Comment: I think you are missing the VPP config in your media folder web.config. Check the readme in the repo for details.